# How to not log Digester?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, apache-commons-digester

I am new to this forum. At first glance this community looks awesome.
I have an easy question. I am logging with log4j and am new to tomcat.
I have found the file where the log rules are set, filename: server.log4j-console.properties

I use for it to not log all digester in BATCH.debug.log

Here is the code in server.log4j-console.properties:

```
# eposerver logger configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, debug-file, console
log4j.logger.systrace=DEBUG, systrace-file
log4j.logger.apptrace=DEBUG, apptrace-file
log4j.logger.ntlogger=INFO, nt-events
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=INFO

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}<%M:%L> -  %m%n

log4j.appender.debug-file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.debug-file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.debug-file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}<%M:%L> -  %m%n
log4j.appender.debug-file.File=${EPO_JAVA_DIR}/apps/var/logs/server/debug.log
log4j.appender.debug-file.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.debug-file.MaxBackupIndex=500

log4j.appender.systrace-file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.systrace-file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.systrace-file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}<%M:%L> -  %m%n
log4j.appender.systrace-file.File=${EPO_JAVA_DIR}/apps/var/logs/server/systrace.log
log4j.appender.systrace-file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.systrace-file.MaxBackupIndex=100

log4j.appender.apptrace-file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.apptrace-file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.apptrace-file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}<%M:%L> -  %m%n
log4j.appender.apptrace-file.File=${EPO_JAVA_DIR}/apps/var/logs/server/apptrace.log
log4j.appender.apptrace-file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.apptrace-file.MaxBackupIndex=100

log4j.appender.nt-events=org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender
log4j.appender.nt-events.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.nt-events.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{2}<%M:%L> -  %m%n0
log4j.appender.nt-events.source=eposerver
```

As you can tell I am new to tomcat, I am assuming this can be done in a couple of lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.digester=INFO
```

Comment: thanks so much for the quick reply, more importantly the correct reply :)